# How to generage .xml or .html with jacoco and spoon

Tags: android, android-testing, spoon

I can setup [spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) with:

```
spoon {
  //...
  codeCoverage = true
}
```

to generage `coverage.ec` files.

How can I generate the reports in `.xml` or `.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this creating your own task using the built-in Jacoco Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['<taskThatProducesEcFile>']) {

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', <another filters...>]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug",     excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "${project.projectDir}/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = files([<your_path_to_ec_file>])
}
```

Comment: You were right, I used `createDebugCoverageReport` tasks right after `spoonDebugAndroidTest` and it generates the reports.